# Mime-type extension does not work with gmail app in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, mime-types, file-extension

This is a two part question. 
Firstly, I cannot get the attachment in the gmail app in iOS to open up with my app. This is not a problem in the native app and the browser based emails. I have done everything in the info-plist to set the mime-type and filename-extension. 
Secondly, is there a way that I don't need to long press on the attachment in the native mail app. Currently, I have to long press then it gives an option of 'Quick Look' and then 'Open with my app'. I would like to avoid this and have it open directly with my app with one click.

Comment: actually I have to long press on it just like in mail app. Is there a way to avoid this long press and just have it open with a single press in one instance.

Comment: You cannot avoid the long press in apps you did not write.

Comment: well actually I found out you can in native mail app. Set the Document types -> roles to Viewer or Quick Look Generator and then when you just click the attachment it will ask you to open in your app. But gmail I have to view the attachment in safari. I was hoping anybody knows how to avoid that.